# How to prevent line wrapping in mosh?

Tags: terminal, word-wrap, mosh

When using ssh (say from OSX to a remote linux machine), lines are (correctly) soft-wrapped, so that resizing the terminal will redraw long lines so that they wrap exactly at the terminal width. However when using mosh instead of ssh, resizing the terminal doesn't re-wrap the lines; they appear to be hard-wrapped (with spaces inserted).

Is that by design, and how to fix it to match ssh behavior?